# Is querySelector,getelementbyclassname etc the proper way to style things in React?

Tags: reactjs

So it seems as if I can use getElementByClassName,querySelector etc... then changing the style the way I always did in vanilla JS works fine, but is this the proper way to do this in React? I have been trying to look this up and I cant seem to  find a clear answer on how to dynamically style properly in React. Should I be usings useRef for every style change? I read I Should have a class for every style change I want and change the className based on a true or false situation??? That doesn't seem correct....  what is the correct way to do a style change in React so I can learn and use what would be considered standard practice in React? side note- I also don't want a special library etc to do styling at this stage. I just want to style the way React expects me to out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

No. The React philosophy is for the view to flow from the state. If you want the view to change, you should call a state setter, and then in the rendering logic, apply the appropriate style based on the state.

You can either toggle a class (with some stylesheet rules), or you can set the `style` prop directly - either is fine, as is mixing those approaches in different situations (it depends on how reusable you need the logic to be).

For example:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [red, setRed] = React.useState(false);
    
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: red ? 'red' : 'white' }}>
        <button onClick={() => setRed(!red)}>Toggle</button>
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

> I read I Should have a class for every style change I want and change the className based on a true or false situation

Sure, you can do that if you want, if you find that you prefer that option.

Comment: Thank you. I will work with that approach.
So in that return, instead of using style, I am assuming I could set the class the same way under className and not use style at all and it would update accordingly.

 What if you want it to change a bunch of things based on the state of red and not just background color and not necessarily change the class. Would I just put a bunch or ternary operaters in the style object?
<div style={{ backgroundColor: red ? 'red' : 'white' , color: red ? 'white' : 'blue' }}>

Comment: In that situation, I'd toggle a class in the JSX, and apply the styling logic needed in the stylesheet.

Comment: So essentially you would have two classess for that scenario and you would add and remove the second class as necessary. Then when its false the first class is applied and when its true both classess are applied and the second class overwrites whats needed in the first?

Also, one other thing I do sometimes that I dont know in React is in JS I used to do querySelectorAll to grab all class elements and then I could run a loop through them and run a function on all of them( ex every other li has a diff color background )

Comment: I'd prefer to have only *one* class. First target the element in the DOM regardless of how things are toggled. By default, apply the first styling (for example, `background-color: white`), and when the class is active, override each of those styles (`background-color: red`).

Comment: `querySelectorAll` should always be avoided in React. If you want separate classes for each element in a loop, you should create a state array where each element of the array corresponds to the styling you want to apply to each element.